# AD LDAP No Password Required

Tags: active-directory, ldap, password, user-accounts

I've got a question about AD accounts that have the setting PASSWD_NOTREQD enabled on them. What exactly does this setting do?

From my own research, it appears that this will cause the account to function in one of two ways either A) no password is required when the account is created and it will ignore password policies and always be able to be set to nothing or B) no password is required when the account is created but if the password is changed it must *still* follow password policies.

Could anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### User passwords and updates

Your second hypothesis is almost correct:

> B) no password is required when the account is created but if the
>   password is changed it must still follow password policies.

For this to make sense, please understand that updating a user account password can be accomplished through two seemingly similar, but very distinct operations:

1. **By *setting* the password**

   - This is done by an administrative user
   - Typically a permission delegated to helpdesk personnel
   - Must adhere to `userAccountControl` settings
   - Not bound by Password History policy settings
2. **By *changing* the password**

   - This is done by the user
   - Typically a part of first authentication attempt after password expiration
   - Must comply with Password Policy *and* `userAccountControl` settings

This means, that an Administrator can ***set*** your password to `null` if your account object permits it (ie. `PASSWD_NOTREQD` is set), regardless of the Password Policy that applies and how long it requires passwords to be.

You cannot *change* your password to `null` however, as the "Password Change" implies that you are replacing a password, not unsetting it. Upon changing the password, the new password will be validated against the effective Password Policy.

I think the easiest way to remember, is that ***Password* Policies apply to *Passwords*** - `PASSWD_NOTREQD` on the other hand, is a measure of whether you are *allowed* to not have a password - in which case the policy is no longer relevant.

---

### Is it dangerous?

`PASSWORD_NOTREQD` might seem like a dangerous flag, but it's not in itself harmful as a lot of mechanisms prevents the usage of `null`-passwords (or "blank passwords"). As noted above, users cannot unset their own AD user passwords by default, and Windows (consumer and Server editions alike) will reject password authentication over the network, for users with blank passwords, by default - that means you can only log on from the console.